# The “feedback always welcome” on Careers 2.0 should point to MSE, not MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mso-mse-split

On the Careers 2.0 web, the “feedback always welcome” link at the page footer continues to link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, however, I believe it should point to here at https://meta.stackexchange.com/, since [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) questions have been migrated here.

Comment: [tag:careers] hasn't been migrated here, rather it hasn't (yet) been migrated to the new MSO. This may still happen during the coming weeks. The new MSO was a clean site with a selected list of questions from what is now MSE moved to the new MSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careers 2.0 feedback links now all point to the right place: http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Thank you for the report!